# g++ doesn't support "-ffast-math -march=native" arguments when I try to run python2 file in conda environment

Tags: python, linux, g++, miniconda, brian

I am trying to run a GitHub repository that is about SNNs. But, when I run the python script, I get a compiler error from the weave package.

Link: https://github.com/djsaunde/lm-snn/blob/master/code/train/csnn_pc_mnist.py

The code generates neuron groups and after that tried to apply STDP backpropagation algorith to them but brian.STDP object couldn't be generated beacuse of the compiler error.

**Error**

```sh
weave.build_tools.CompileError: error: Command "/home/mzp7/workspace/DSNN/Examples/lm-snn/miniconda2/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ -fno-strict-aliasing -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O3 -pipe -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/mzp7/workspace/DSNN/Examples/lm-snn/miniconda2/include -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/mzp7/workspace/DSNN/Examples/lm-snn/miniconda2/include -fPIC -I/home/mzp7/workspace/DSNN/Examples/lm-snn/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weave -I/home/mzp7/workspace/DSNN/Examples/lm-snn/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weave/scxx -I/home/mzp7/workspace/DSNN/Examples/lm-snn/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/mzp7/workspace/DSNN/Examples/lm-snn/miniconda2/include/python2.7 -c /home/mzp7/workspace/DSNN/Examples/lm-snn/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weave/scxx/weave_imp.cpp -o /tmp/weave-mzp7-UMTCud/python27_intermediate/compiler_7d6a1f80b8499f1aba77652aa8d9d6d7/home/mzp7/workspace/DSNN/Examples/lm-snn/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weave/scxx/weave_imp.o -MMD -MF /tmp/weave-mzp7-UMTCud/python27_intermediate/compiler_7d6a1f80b8499f1aba77652aa8d9d6d7/home/mzp7/workspace/DSNN/Examples/lm-snn/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weave/scxx/weave_imp.o.d -O3 -ffast-math -march=native" failed with exit status 1
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-ffast-math -march=native'; did you mean '-fsso-struct=native'?
```

I use the miniconda2 environment.

Conda package: libgcc

Pip packages:
numpy
matplotlib
scipy
brian
weave
sympy
networkx
pandas
sklearn
brian2

Thank you.